Problema con controlador cuando envia los datos a la vista
Estimados tengo un problema con asp netcore, entre el metodo list y el metodo detail
lo que ocurre es que tengo 1 metodo que me trae una lista si el parametro de entrada es null , pero si no lo es , entonces me devuelve solo el registro que encuentra segun el parametro que le mande. Aquí dejo el metodo del controller.
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetResponsables(String? Rut)
    {
        if (Rut == null)
        {
            return _context.SvtResponsables != null ?
            View("Clinica", await _context.SvtResponsables.ToListAsync()) :
            Problem("Entity set 'softyvet_dbContext.SvtResponsables'  is null.");
        }
        else {
            var responsable= await _context.SvtResponsables.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m =>m.RutResponsable==Rut);
            return View("Clinica",responsable);
        }
    }


ese enlace va a el controler de la siguiente manera
 Clinica
y funciona me retorna el listado de datos

el tema es que cuando le paso como parametro 1 registro , el controlador me trae el registro bien , pero la vista sigue mostrando el listado completo.

pero la grilla muestra la lista completa

Aquí dejo la vista razor
@model IEnumerable<SofTiVet.Models.SvtResponsable>

                                                
                                                    RESPONSABLE
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Rut Responsable</th>
                                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                                                    <th>Dirección</th>
                                                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                                                    <th>Email</th>

                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>

                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="table-responsable">
                                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                                {




                                                 <tr>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.RutResponsable)</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.NombreResponsable)</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ApellidosResponsable)</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.DirResponsable)</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.FonoResponsable)</td>
                                                <td></td>
                                              

                                               <td>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                 }
                                                
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

Aquí dejo el codigo del botón buscar ya que va por ajax
      function getResponsableByRut(rut){

        $.ajax({

           
            url: "@Url.Action("GetResponsables","Clinica")",
            data: {
                Rut: rut,
            },
            type: "GET",

            success: function (result) {
            }
            

        });

    }

Por favor su ayuda

Saludos. La 2da y 4ta imagen me parecen las mismas; en tu 3er imagen que asumo va en relación al código del primer bloque donde está GetResponsables observo que _context.SvtResponsables.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m =>m.RutResponsable==Rut) retorna un solo objeto mientras que la vista espera (al parecer) procesar un Array/List/Enumeration de objetos.

Al parecer el método ajax no esta actualizando la tabla de la vista, prueba con un console log para validar que el dato llega al navegador. luego utiliza esos datos para actualizar la vista mediante javascript. lo usual es que en la funcióin success se escriba la lógica para actualizar la tabla.
  function getResponsableByRut(rut){

    $.ajax({

       
        url: "@Url.Action("GetResponsables","Clinica")",
        data: {
            Rut: rut,
        },
        type: "GET",

        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
            
            // incluir aquí la lógica para actualizar la tabla. 
        }
        

    });

}

Nota al moderador: no puedo comentar, por eso puse esto como respuesta.
